# No module named rest_framework after successful build from Dockerfile

Tags: python, docker, django-rest-framework

In my Dockerfile, I pip install requirements like this:

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
```

Here's my requirements:

```
djangorestframework==3.9.2
Django>=2.0,<3.0
psycopg2>=2.7,<3.0
```

...and here's my installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ....
    'rest_framework',
]
```

...problem occurs after adding this line.

What am I missing?

Comment: Not sure why, but in my project, I also have `django-rest-framework==0.1.0` in `requirements.txt`. Maybe try adding it.

Comment: Isn't it "djangorestframework". Not sure which one is right but in tutorials these are written together.

Comment: Well, I have both. And not sure why :)

Comment: which django version you have installed? the frame work required Django (1.11, 2.0, 2.1, 2.2)